# Please help me translate this sentence and if possible, meaning of each word in it

Tags: lyrics

Please translate this phrase for me, and if possible, please also explain the meaning of every word used in it: "눈 감으면 봄은 아득하고". Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you consulted a dictionary? or do you have a specific problem in translating this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

When I close my eyes, the spring seems far away.

- 눈(을): Eye
- (내가) 감으면: Close
- 봄은: Spring + 은(for a subject)
- 아득하고: Far away(that you cannot reach it or imagine it)

Since 아득하다 might be difficult voca, I want to leave some examples.

1. 지평선(the horizon)이 아득하다.
2. 아득히 먼 미래